# Crystal reports asking for user and password

Tags: crystal-reports, vb.net-2010

i am using crystal reports and vb.net

whenever user or i as developer open crystal report, it ask for user and password. my code that i am using in vb.net is below. how can i disable it

my codes are

```
enter code here
 Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
    cryRpt.Load("\\192.168.1.150\Bashir Impex
```

Files\Department Folders\IT\cpv.rpt")

```
    Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As 
    ParameterFieldDefinitions
    Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As 
        ParameterFieldDefinition
    Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
    Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New 
     ParameterDiscreteValue

    crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = TextBox2.Text
    crParameterFieldDefinitions = _
    cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
    crParameterFieldDefinition = _
   crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("cpvid")
    crParameterValues = 
   crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues

    crParameterValues.Clear()
    crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
    crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)

    Form5.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
    Form5.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()

    Form5.Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by adding one line to my code

```
cryRpt.SetDatabaseLogon(user, pwd)
```